# Post method returns 404 in Asp.net core Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Routes code below:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Controller code below :

```
// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]Employee employee)
        {
            employeeManager.CreateAsync(employee);
        }
```

All other methods working except the post method.

call from angular component :

```
 onSubmit(employeeItems: any) {        
        console.log(employeeItems);
        this.getData();
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        this.http.post('api/Employee/Post', employeeItems, { headers: headers }).subscribe();
        this.createEmployeeFlag = false;
    }
```

> I tried even from Postman, but no luck.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url and route templates do not match

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Employee employee) {
        await employeeManager.CreateAsync(employee);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and update your calling URL to call the default endpoint `api/Employee`

```
onSubmit(employeeItems: any) {        
    console.log(employeeItems);
    this.getData();
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    this.http.post('api/Employee', employeeItems, { headers: headers }).subscribe();
    this.createEmployeeFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for "and update your calling URL to call the default endpoint api/Employee" this was the problem in my case!! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that you would need in your service, there are two issues here, first is the URL, it needs to be the complete URL path. The second is is that you are trying to subscribe to something before mapping it to a `Observable`

```
onSubmit(employeeItems: any) {
    let url: string = 'http://localhost/api/employee'; //this will be the complete url that you would hit with say postman  
    this.getData(); //I'm not sure what this is so I'm leaving it here
    this.http.post(url, employeeItems)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .Subscribe((response: any) => {
        //do whatever with the response here.
      });
    this.createEmployeeFlag = false;
}
```

I would suggest breaking this up into a `*.service.ts` file.

`*.service.ts`

```
public postEmployee(employeeItems: any): Observable<any> {
  let url: string = 'http://localhost/api/employee'; //this will be the complete url that you would hit with say postman  
  this.http.post(url, employeeItems)
   .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

inside your `*.component.ts`

constructor(private service: Service) {}

```
onSubmit(employeeItems: any) {
  this.getData(); //I'm not sure what this is so I'm leaving it here
  this.service.postEmployee(employeeItems)
    .Subscribe((response: any) => {
      //do whatever with the response here.
    });
  this.createEmployeeFlag = false;
}
```